# Method freezes when 0 is the input

Tags: java, logic, freeze

For a programming course, I have to write a polynomial class using a LinkedList.  Everything is working fine, but whenever two polynomials have terms that contain a 0 as the power, (7^0), the method freezes.  I am pretty sure the problem arrises in the simplifyPoly() method, specifically right as it attempts to add the new term into the new polynomial.  I don't understand why this could be happening.  I am hoping that someone can answer this and tell me why this is happening or how I could fix it before tomorrow night since that's when its due!  Thank you in advance!

```
public class Main3{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Polynomial poly = new Polynomial();

        poly.addValue(2,3);
        poly.addValue(4,2);
        poly.addValue(5,1);
        poly.addValue(7,0);

        poly.printPoly();

        Polynomial poly2 = new Polynomial();

        poly2.addValue(4,3);
        poly2.addValue(6,2);
        poly2.addValue(5,0);

        poly2.printPoly();

        Polynomial sum = poly.addPoly(poly2);

        sum.printPoly();

        System.out.println("Degree of first printed Polynomial "+poly.degPoly());
    }
}

class Polynomial {
    private LinkedList list;
    private int size;

    public Polynomial(){
        this.list = new LinkedList();
        this.size = this.list.getSize();
    }

    public LinkedList getList(){
        return this.list;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return this.size;
    }

    public int degPoly(){
        return this.list.getHead().getNext().getDegree();
    }

    public void addValue(int c, int d){
        this.list.addValue(c,d);
        this.size = this.list.getSize();
    }

    public void removeValue(int c, int d){
        this.list.deleteValue(c,d);
        this.size = this.list.getSize();
    }

    public void printPoly(){
        this.list.printList();
    }

    public Polynomial addPoly(Polynomial b){
        Polynomial one = this.simplifyPoly('a');
        Polynomial two = b.simplifyPoly('a');
        Polynomial sum = new Polynomial();
        for (Node current = one.getList().getHead().getNext(); current != one.getList().getTail(); current = current.getNext()){
            sum.addValue(current.getCoefficient(), current.getDegree());
        }
        for (Node current = two.getList().getHead().getNext(); current != two.getList().getTail(); current = current.getNext()){
            sum.addValue(current.getCoefficient(), current.getDegree());
        }
        sum = sum.simplifyPoly('a');
        return sum;
    }

    public Polynomial subPoly(Polynomial b){
        Polynomial one = this.simplifyPoly('a');
        Polynomial two = b.simplifyPoly('a');
        Polynomial difference = new Polynomial();
        for (Node current = one.getList().getHead().getNext(); current != one.getList().getTail(); current = current.getNext()){
            difference.addValue(current.getCoefficient(), current.getDegree());
        }
        for (Node current = two.getList().getHead().getNext(); current != two.getList().getTail(); current = current.getNext()){
            difference.addValue(current.getCoefficient(), current.getDegree());
        }
        difference = difference.simplifyPoly('s');
        return difference;
    }

    public Polynomial multPoly(Polynomial b){
        Polynomial one = this.simplifyPoly('a');
        Polynomial two = b.simplifyPoly('a');
        Polynomial product = new Polynomial();
        for (Node current = one.getList().getHead().getNext(); current != one.getList().getTail(); current = current.getNext()){
            for (Node current2 = two.getList().getHead().getNext(); current2 != two.getList().getTail(); current2 = current2.getNext()){
                product.addValue((current.getCoefficient() * current2.getCoefficient()), (current.getDegree() + current2.getDegree()));
            }
        }
        product = product.simplifyPoly('a');
        return product;
    }

    public Polynomial simplifyPoly(char caller){
        Polynomial temp = new Polynomial();
        Node current = this.list.getHead().getNext(); current = current.getNext();
        Node prior = this.list.getHead().getNext();
        while (prior != this.list.getTail()){
            if (prior.getDegree() == current.getDegree()){
                if (caller == 'a') {
                    int coefficient = prior.getCoefficient() + current.getCoefficient();
                    temp.addValue(coefficient, current.getDegree());
                } else if (caller == 's'){
                    temp.addValue((prior.getCoefficient() - current.getCoefficient()), current.getDegree());
                }
                prior = prior.getNext(); prior = prior.getNext();
                current = current.getNext(); current = current.getNext();
            } else {
                temp.addValue(prior.getCoefficient(), prior.getDegree());
                prior = prior.getNext();
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    private int size;

    public LinkedList(){
        this.head = new Node(this.tail);
        this.tail = new Node(this.head);
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public Node getHead(){
        return this.head;
    }

    public Node getTail(){
        return this.tail;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return this.size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (this.head.getNext() == this.tail || this.tail.getNext() == this.head || this.size == 0);
    }



    public void addValue(int c, int d){
        Node temp = new Node(c, d, null);

        if (isEmpty()){
            temp.setNext(this.tail);
            this.head.setNext(temp);
            this.tail.setNext(temp);
        } else if (this.head.getNext().getDegree() < d){
            temp.setNext(this.head.getNext());
            this.head.setNext(temp);
        } else if (this.tail.getNext().getDegree() > d){
            temp.setNext(this.tail);
            this.tail.getNext().setNext(temp);
            this.tail.setNext(temp);
        } else {
            Node current = this.head.getNext(); current = current.getNext();
            Node prior = this.head.getNext();

            while (current.getDegree() >= d){
                //if (current.getDegree() == d){
                //  current.setCoefficient((current.getCoefficient() + c));
                //}
                current = current.getNext();
                prior = prior.getNext();
            }

            temp.setNext(current);
            prior.setNext(temp);
        }
        size++;
    }

    public void deleteValue(int c, int d){
        Node current = this.head.getNext();current = current.getNext();
        Node prior = this.head.getNext();
        if (!isEmpty()){
            while (current != this.tail){
                if (current.getDegree() == d && current.getCoefficient() == c){
                    prior.setNext(current.getNext());
                } else {
                    current = current.getNext();
                    prior = prior.getNext();
                }
            }
        }
        this.size--;
    }

    public boolean findNode(int c, int d){
        Node current = this.head.getNext();
        while (current != tail){
            if (current.getCoefficient() == c && current.getDegree() == d){
                return true;
            } else {
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void printList(){
        if (isEmpty()) {System.out.println("No terms in equation"); return;} // breaks method if the list is empty
        Node current = this.getHead().getNext();
        while (current != this.tail){
            if (current.getNext() != this.tail){
                System.out.print(current.getCoefficient()+"x^"+current.getDegree()+" + ");
                current = current.getNext();
            } else if (current.getDegree() == 1 && this.tail != current.getNext()) {
                System.out.print(current.getCoefficient()+" + ");
                current = current.getNext();
            } else if (current.getDegree() == 1 && this.tail == current.getNext()) {
                System.out.println(current.getCoefficient());
                current = current.getNext();
            } else if (current.getDegree() == 0 && this.tail != current.getNext()) {
                System.out.print(1+" + ");
                current = current.getNext();
            } else if (current.getDegree() == 0 && this.tail == current.getNext()) {
                System.out.println(1);
                current = current.getNext();
            } else {
                System.out.println(current.getCoefficient()+"x^"+current.getDegree());
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Node {
    private int coefficient;
    private int degree;
    private Node next;

    public Node(int c, int d, Node n){
        this.coefficient = c;
        this.degree = d;
        this.next = n;
    }

    public Node(Node n){
        this.next = n;
    }

    public int getCoefficient(){
        return this.coefficient;
    }

    public int getDegree(){
        return this.degree;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return this.next;
    }

    public void setCoefficient(int c){
        this.coefficient = c;
    }

    public void setDegree(int d){
        this.degree = d;
    }

    public void setNext(Node n){
        this.next = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stepping through this with a debugger would enable you to find out very quickly what's happening.  Also, you should put some explanatory comments at the top of each method, as this code is extremely hard to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your `LinkedList` constructor.

```
public LinkedList(){
    this.head = new Node(this.tail);
    this.tail = new Node(this.head);
    this.size = 0;
}
```

So you're creating two nodes here, and the one at `tail` points back to the one at `head`.  This means that the list is circular before you've even started inserting data into it.  You're also asserting that the size is zero, even though there are two nodes.

But because the list is circular, as soon as you try to traverse it, you'll end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: You have not looked at my addValue() method in the LinkedList class.  The addValue method takes care of the size and it is not a doubly linkedlist so it is not circular.  The getNext() method for the tail node just points to the value right before, it not the head value.  It is pointing to the head node in the constructor since that is what would be so in an empty list.

Comment: I have looked at all of your code.  And I've never heard of a linked list where the tail element's "next" reference points to the element before it.  That's the problem that is making `prior` skip over the tail and run in a circle when you write `prior = prior.getNext(); prior = prior.getNext();` in the middle of your `simplify` method.  Do not make your tail point to other elements.

Comment: The program spec requires a tail node that points to the last element.  I did not want to create a special method just for that so i used the function of getNext to do that.  The reason that prior moves twice in simplify is that once it combines two terms next to each other, they both don't need to be combined to anything else so we must move two terms in the polynomial.

Comment: Yes, I understand why prior moves twice.  But if `prior` gets to be the second-to-last node, then the first `getNext()` assigns it to the tail, and the second `getNext()` assigns it back to the second-to-last node.  That is the reason for your endless loop.  You can try to justify it all you want, but this is why you have the problem.

Comment: Oh, I understand you now. I did not see what you meant with the double prior move.  It worked now, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code, I'll point out a few but it won't get them working unless you follow David Wallace's suggestion and work on stepping through it with a debugger, as well as comment it out better.
1 - this code

```
 } else if (this.tail.getNext().getDegree() > d){
            temp.setNext(this.tail);
            this.tail.getNext().setNext(temp);
            this.tail.setNext(temp);
        } else {
```

will cause your tail to point to temp which will point back to tail. That is causing the infinite loop inside your simplifyPoly() method inside addPoly(), after you print your poly2, since you're attempting to traverse that list.
2 - if you attempt to fix that by doing

```
this.tail = temp
```

, you'll now run into another infinite loop on the line that says 
`poly.addValue(5,0)`
because you're doing a while loop that keeps going while the degree of 0 is greater or equal to 0:

```
 while (current.getDegree() >= d){
            //if (current.getDegree() == d){
            //  current.setCoefficient((current.getCoefficient() + c));
            //}
            current = current.getNext();
            prior = prior.getNext();
        }
```

Anyway, that's just ot get you going. Find yourself a good tutorial on how to use a java debugger so that you can step through your code and get better understanding of it.